# PHP form displays on anchor click and jumps to right place in ie but not chrome. No JS

Tags: php, html, css

I have built a working form that does what I want in IE an upon cross testing I have found that it jumps to the lower id= in Chrome instead of the upper name= as in IE. I know the name tag has been depreciated but I for the life of me cannot get this to open and move the form to the top any other way. I need this to work without JS. I have never used PHP before and have built this around a template for a php form. Im not sure how to hack this one any further. I have put in a lot of work to get this functional and any changes I make just break it completely.

So far I have changed names and id's but everything breaks it. I know it has to do with having both a name and an id but I'm not sure how to fix this without JS. I am testing on IE 11 and Chrome 77. I don't so much care about "old browsers" but would like to get most of the stuff being used on win 7 and up, so legacy support is not an issue but I do want to follow best practices. I am new to forms so I'm not sure where to go from here. As I said, it works, just not everywhere.

```css
#quotejump {
      display: none;
    }

    #quotejump:target {
      display: block;
    }

    .form-style{
      max-width: 400px;
      margin: 10px auto;
      padding: 0px;
      background: #a0a0a0;
      font-family: inherit;
      border-top-left-radius: 50px;
      border-top-right-radius: 50px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .form-style a, .form-style h1{
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      background: linear-gradient(45deg, #00f, #0ff);
      padding: 20px 0;
      font-size: 30px;
      font-weight: 300;
      width: 100%;
      color: #fff;
      margin: 0;
      border-radius: 50px;
    }

    .form-style input[type="text"],
    .form-style input[type="date"],
    .form-style input[type="datetime"],
    .form-style input[type="email"],
    .form-style input[type="number"],
    .form-style input[type="search"],
    .form-style input[type="time"],
    .form-style input[type="url"],
    .form-style textarea,
    .form-style select {
      -webkit-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
      -ms-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
      outline: none;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      width: 92%;
      background: #fff;
      margin-bottom: 4%;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      padding: 3%;
      color: #;
      font-family: inherit;
      border-radius: 30px;
    }

    .form-style input[type="text"]:focus,
    .form-style input[type="date"]:focus,
    .form-style input[type="datetime"]:focus,
    .form-style input[type="email"]:focus,
    .form-style input[type="number"]:focus,
    .form-style input[type="search"]:focus,
    .form-style input[type="time"]:focus,
    .form-style input[type="url"]:focus,
    .form-style textarea:focus,
    .form-style select:focus
    {
      box-shadow: 0 0 5px #43D1AF;
      padding: 3%;
      border: 1px solid #43D1AF;
    }

    .quotebutton {
      text-decoration: none;
      border: none;
      background: linear-gradient(45deg, #00f, #0ff);
      border-radius: 30px;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 60px;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 30px;
      margin: 0 2px;
      transition: 0.25s;
    }

    .form-style a:hover {
      -webkit-transform:scale(1.25);
      -moz-transform:scale(1.25);
      -ms-transform:scale(1.25);
      -o-transform:scale(1.25);
      transform:scale(1.25);
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
      -ms-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
      -o-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
      box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
      position:relative;
      z-index:5;
    }

    .quotebutton:hover  {
      -webkit-transform:scale(1.25);
      -moz-transform:scale(1.25);
      -ms-transform:scale(1.25);
      -o-transform:scale(1.25);
      transform:scale(1.25);
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
      -ms-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
      -o-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
      box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
      position:relative;
      z-index:5;
    }
```

```html
    <h1>Top of Page</h1>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <p>some filler text to move the page down</p>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <a name="quotejump">&nbsp;</a>
    <div class="calltoaction">
       <h1>Contact us today for a quote!</h1>
       <p>Due to the nature of the customization process all prices are figured for each specific job. This allows us to ensure the quality of your products while maintaining the lowest prices possible for you. You won't find this quality cheaper anywhere else! We guarantee it! </p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-style">
       <a href="#quotejump" >Get Your FREE Quote Here!</a>
       <div id="quotejump">
          <span id="quoteform"><br />Learn How We Can Save You Money On Quality Produts Today!
             <form method="post" action="send_mail.php">
                <p><input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="Your Name" required></p>
      <p><input type="email" name="email_address" placeholder="Email Address" required></p>
      <p><textarea name="comments" placeholder="Type your message" maxlength="1000" ></textarea></p>
      <p><button class="quotebutton">Submit Form</button></p>
             </form>
          </span> 
       </div>
    </div>
```

It should jump to the name tag and it does in IE 11 but jumps to the id tag in chrome. Any idea how to fix this without messing up the php and the display hidden until clicked on? I tried a check box but couldn't make it jump. I don't want it to be able to toggle as I want it to stay open once clicked on. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[IE11 What it should do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxAi4.png)

[Chrome What it does in chrome when opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9JbW.png)

[Image of form before opening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3PWE.png)

Comment: `<a href="#quotejump">` jumps to `<div id="quotejump">` It does not jumps to `<a name="quotejump">` See link bookmarks https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

Comment: @bron, Lol I've been living on that page. If I change the name= to id= the display: hidden; quits working. Why is one jumping to one spot and the other to another? I want them both to go to the area that says <a name="quotejump">&nbsp;</a>.

Comment: Hi GodsLilDrummer. The correct syntax for "bookmarks" is  `<a href="#myquote">Goto quote</a> ... Text lines ... <a id="myquote" name="quotejump">&nbsp;</a> ... Text lines ... <a href="#myquote">Goto quote</a>`. Any number of anchors with href="#myquote" is allowed. The id (in this example id="myquote") must be unique on the page.

Comment: @bron I'm afraid I don't understand that in this situation. There is only one anchor needed. The name= is the jump to spot. The id= is what is hidden. The href= is the link that does dual duty, both displaying what is hidden and jumping to the bookmark. If I change name= to id= then I have two identical id's. I don't need two links, only one that does two things.

Comment: You mentioned that Chrome is jumping to the lower `id=".."` instead of the upper `name=".."` as in IE.
As defined in html, Chrome is working correct because a bookmark has two parts:
(a) the bookmark `<a id="myquote" name="..">&nbsp;</a>`, the point you can jump to, and
(b) an anchor `<a href="#myquote">Goto quote</a>` (the # means id).
The anchor is the element you can click on to jump to the bookmark-id.
In your html, the `name=".."` is a reference used by php to read the contents from that particular form field.

Comment: Giving the id= the same value as name= will hide the element because in your style is defined:
`#quotejump { display: none; } #quotejump:target { display: block; }`.
Therefore you have to give id= another value, for example:
`<a id="jumpbookmark" name="quotejump">&nbsp;</a>`.
Then you can use an anchor `<a href="#jumpbookmark">Goto jump bookmark</a>` to jump to `id="jumpbookmark"`.

Comment: @bron Well yeah, but when I do that my form no longer displays when I click the link. Like I said I can get one to work or the other. I just want to make it open and jump from one click. I really appreciate your help but It still wont work right.

Comment: Two (or more) _different_ actions on 1 click event can only be done in Javascript with an `addEventListener(..)` www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp